# Perpage Resets Late In Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, perpage

I'm using a custom bst file that produces code like this in the bbl file:

```
\bibitem[Fodor(1981)]{Fodor:Representations}
\stepcounter{bibitem}
% \theperpage \lastpage % debugging code 
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\theperpage}{\lastpage}}
  {\pageswitchfalse}{\pageswitchtrue}\ifthenelse{\isodd{0\theperpage}}
  {\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{1pt}} {\ifpageswitch{Fodor, J.}\else
  \rule[0.5ex]{2em}{1pt}\fi}\let\lastpage=\theperpage{} 
  % \theperpage \lastpage % debugging code 
  (1981).
\newblock {\em Representations}.
\newblock Cambridge MA, MIT Press.
```

The point of this is (i) to print a rule instead of the author's name when the author is the same as in the last entry but (ii) to reprint the author's name if the entry occurs at the top of an even page. (I had a lot of help with this code from people on comp.text.tex.)

When used with a previous book project (ten years ago), this code worked fine. Now it fails. Instead of the first entry reprinting the author's name, the second entry does so. So I get a rule for the first entry (on an even page), then the name in the second one (if such there is).

The problem is that the perpage counter is being reset late. If I activate the debugging code, then it prints the number of the *previous* page, not the *current* page. The perpage counter then gets updated *after* the entry is complete, and the next one prints the name of the author, since the \equal test now fails.

I'm using natbib because this is a collection of papers some of which are quite old, and then were written using natbib. I do not want to have to go through and change everything to biblatex, though I'm curious whether this problem is more easily solved there.

Thanks for any help.